# Alternative to 'object' type in Typescript without casting/extending

Tags: typescript

I have a number of functions that accept an object literal as a payload. `unknown` is too loose a type and in some cases I do not want to use generics. Using `object` works but triggers a warning

```
Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)).
Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys
```

However `Record<string, unknown>` doesn't work well and yields `Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.`

What can I use instead of `object` that would work well?

```ts
export interface StackInput {
  foo: string
}

const getStackHashRecord = (stack: StackInput) => createHashRecord(stack) // error
const createHashRecord = (obj: Record<string, unknown>): void => {}

const getStackHashObject = (stack: StackInput) => createHashObject(stack)
const createHashObject = (obj: object): void => {} // warning
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRhwGsBJJMAV3gG8BYAKDjnQggC44BnGKZAc0YBfRo2wQkPOP2AxCJABKYuACwBKwcVAAmcALxwAFDxKd52MhWoBKfQD442KMEyolqjVu3GiF62IkpJxc3ZXVNaF0DQwgAIwArTk9IgB4ePiR%20ABo4SiRiJAgAdyQ7a04ANwgEKIcaEQYAyXgZOV9idxUAeQTNeGiTCzN28ioYWz0HYNdgTp74vp8SfwZxZsdnGbne7H6jOMS4A77yuCqa%20zh6oA).

Comment: `const getStackHashRecord = (stack: StackInput) => { const {...props} = stack; createHashRecord({ ...props }); }`

Comment: I kind of hate that linter rule, since `object` is perfectly useful as what it is: a way to exclude primitives like `string`.  Personally I'd ditch the rule and keep `object`.  But if you want an alternative, the linked questions have answers.

Comment: @jcalz I see `Record<string, any>` which works. Got thoughts on that vs `object`?

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are.  A `number` is assignable to `Record<string, any>` whereas it is not assignable to `object`.

Comment: @jcalz what do you mean a number? as in ` createHashRecord(2)`? That doesn't work in either.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about that.  Not sure why I thought that was.   In that case I think `Record<string, any>` will probably work, since (I believe) it's special cased to allow interfaces where `Record<string, unknown>` is not.